# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. I have add the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule Also

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<form [formGroup]="resetform" (ngSubmit)="resetPassword()" class="loginform-container">
     //foo
</form>
```

I have added the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` but this issue still persists.

Comment: Remember that, sometimes, when you add a module you need re-start the server: `ng serve`

Comment: Make sure that you have imported in the correct modules